# Three.js: Fill mesh shaderMaterial with one color up to certain position

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am having some trouble understanding Three.js shaders. I am attempting to color a mesh with a color, but only up to a certain position. So far, this is the closest I have come to achieving that.

- I need to make the green color "stop" at 50% of the mesh height
- For the remainder of the mesh (above 50%), either fill with another color or don't fill at all (both cases would work here)

**Shader code:**

```
    const _VS = `

        uniform vec3 bboxMin;
        uniform vec3 bboxMax;

        varying vec2 vUv;

        void main() {
            vUv.x = (position.x - bboxMin.x) / (bboxMax.x - bboxMin.x);
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
        }
    `;

    const _FS = `

        uniform vec3 incompleteColor;
        uniform vec3 completenessColor;

        varying vec2 vUv;

        void main() {

            gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(incompleteColor, completenessColor, vUv.x), 1.0);
        }
    `;
```

**Javascript code:**

```
            let geometries = element.geometry.clone(); // Inherits geometries from parent element

            let wall = new THREE.Mesh(
                geometries,
                new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                    uniforms: {
                        incompleteColor: {
                            value: new THREE.Color('red')
                        },
                        completenessColor: {
                            value: new THREE.Color('green')
                        },
                        bboxMin: {
                            value: element.geometry.boundingBox.min
                        },
                        bboxMax: {
                            value: element.geometry.boundingBox.max
                        }
                    },
                    vertexShader: _VS,
                    fragmentShader: _FS,
                })
            );

            wall.castShadow = true;
            wall.position.setFromMatrixPosition(element.matrixWorld);
            wall.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(element.matrixWorld, 'XYZ');

            scene.add(wall);
```

**This image helps illustrate what I want to achieve:**

**LEFT:** How it looks with the code I posted (Three.js scene)

**RIGHT:** What I want to achieve

[image: Three.js scene and the desired result]

I have spent several hours researching this issue and I can't seem to find an example that points me in the right direction.

Comment: Have a look at this forum topic: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/color-bottom-x-of-a-boxgeometry-using-faces/18502/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the GLSL `step()` function. You can [read about it here](https://thebookofshaders.com/glossary/?search=step).

```glsl
void main() {
    // First, create a hard step when UV crosses the 0.5 threshold
    float switch = step(0.5, vUv.x);

    // Then use that hard step on your mix function
    gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(incompleteColor, completenessColor, switch), 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Thx, this did just what I needed!